# php joomla session lifetime settings

Tags: php, joomla1.5

I have searched through the google and also joomla forums but didn't got what exactly I was looking for.

- My main purpose is to set the joomla session live for ever.
- Many forums says its not good to keep a higher value (security issues) but I don't want to consider that right now.

My question is:

What if I set the session lifetime value to "0" (Zero), will the session be active for ever? or the user will NOT be able to login completely?

Comment: why in the world, you want to set session for ever?

Comment: Why not try out? Also, how about setting it to a very high value (e.g. a full year)?

Comment: @Pekka : I did try out with zero. It didn't log me out. But looking through joomla docs, it didn't gave clear picture. Most of the forums and joomla docs says to set the value to higher number. But was wondering why need to higher value if it can be done with Zero!

@Sarfraz : Its an offline LAN application, where user needs to be logged in all the time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know Joomla's session management functions in detail, but I assume they are based on ordinary cookies. With those, a value of `0` will lead to [the cookie being deleted](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) at the end of the session, so you may want to go with an impossibly large value.

Comment: based on your assumption, if its working the same way in joomla, then if I set the value to Zero, the user session will be kept live until the browser is closed? So user will have to login again when they re-open the browser? But if they dont close, they will be logged in forever?

Comment: @jtanmay yes that is the way it should be according to the setcookie() docs.

Comment: Thanks for your time and answer. I have got the clarification. I am already doing a auto-login when the browser is opened. So setting the value to zero will do the trick for me.

Thanks again.

Comment: @jtanmay ah okay, I understood you wrong here, I thought you need an "eternal session" regardless from whether a browser is running or not. You're welcome.